# Bootstrap jQuery library conflict: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, conflicting-libraries

I am trying to add the popover function to my code, I made it work before using almost this exact same code and lost that progress permanently, now I am unsure of what I did to fix it in the first place. I'm sure it is a simple oversight but I'm bankrupt of ideas.

I get an error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function(…)"

```
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function($){

        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
        });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

In essence, I understand the nature of the problem but am unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: Is the html syntax issue addressed by the answer in your source code or you just missed it when posting to SO?

Comment: `<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` you are missing the closing tag on script src inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

please fix syntax error in script tag

old script

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"</script>
```

new script

```
 <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```